# Does webdriver support media query?

Tags: android, selenium, cucumber, webdriver

I am executing automated tests via cucumber on iOS and Android everything is green on iOS however the same tests, same code running on Android fail because of missing content in the browser. After speaking to one of our front end devs he suggested I find out if webdriver for android supports media query as checking manually in the browser (not using webdriver) works fine.

Thanks in advance,
Ian